# NodeJS execSync is File Exist using Bash Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I'm trying to use unix utils in nodejs. I'm testing advantages. I have a function like that:

```
function unix_creat(src){
  if(src != undefined && typeof src === 'string'){
    const { execSync } = require("child_process");
    if(execSync(`if [ -f "${src}" ]; then echo "1"; else echo "0"; fi`, {encoding: 'utf8'}).includes(1) === true){
      return(1);
    } else { return(0); }
  } else { return(0); };
};
return(unix_creat('test.js'));
```

In this code, `` execSync(`if [ -f "${src}" ]; then echo "1"; else echo "0"; fi`, {encoding: 'utf8'}).includes(1) === true) `` part has problems. When I console.log this, I get valid output. When I launch all code, I get this:

```
user@pc:~/Project/UnixCommand$ node index.js
{}
```

How can I get 1 or 0 ?

** I use **.includes(1)** part because output is somehow weird:

```
1

{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved. Actually there's no problem at all. I just used my index.js file as module. I was making module so that make sanse.